# syntax error, unexpected '<' using eval and base64

Tags: php, encoding, base64, eval

I'm trying to encode a simple code but I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\test.php(2) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

This is the code:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
Enter your command: <input type='text' name='cmd'> <input type='submit' name='execute'       value='Execute'>
</form>


echo $_POST['cmd'];
```

This is the base64_encode with eval:

```
<?
eval(base64_decode('PGZvcm0gbWV0aG9kPSJQT1NUIiBhY3Rpb249IiI+CkVudGVyIHlvdXIgY29tbWFuZDogPGlu     cHV0IHR5cGU9J3RleHQnIG5hbWU9J2NtZCc+IDxpbnB1dCB0eXBlPSdzdWJtaXQnIG5hbWU9J2V4ZWN1dGUnIHZhbHVl     PSdFeGVjdXRlJz4KPC9mb3JtPgoKCmVjaG8gJF9QT1NUWydjbWQnXTsK'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to eval non-php code (html form)

Comment: and what is this echo $_POST['cmd']? is that a HTML code?

Comment: No, it is PHP code, but it should be surrounded with php tags <?php echo $_POST['cmd'] ?>

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the PHP tags around your code:

```
<?php

    // Any PHP code as needed

?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    Enter your command: <input type='text' name='cmd'> <input type='submit' name='execute'       value='Execute'>
    </form>

<?php

    echo $_POST['cmd'];
?>
```